# Rest-assured - Schema to use cannot be null

Tags: automated-testing, api-testing, rest-api, rest-assured, api-automation

Using the code below, I'm getting the following error:

My code:

```
    @Test
    public void get_user_API_Schema_Test() {

        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://gorest.co.in";
        given().log().all()
        .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer _FWTKt73f0EeVrfWj7d3sKoLMnw_9dqVcs0k")
                    .when().log().all()
                .get("/public-api/users?first_name=Reina&gender=male&status=active")
                    .then().log().all()
                        .assertThat()
                .statusCode(200).and().body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("C:\\Users\\ASHUTOSH SINGH\\eclipse-workspace\\RestAPI2020\\src\\test\\java\\com\\rest\\api\\schema\\getuserschema.json"));

    }
```

Returns the following error:

```
FAILED: get_user_API_Schema_Test
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Schema to use cannot be null
    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.validateSchemaIsNotNull(JsonSchemaValidator.java:270)
    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.access$300(JsonSchemaValidator.java:75)
    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator$JsonSchemaValidatorFactory.create(JsonSchemaValidator.java:281)
    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchema(JsonSchemaValidator.java:166)
    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath(JsonSchemaValidator.java:117)
    at com.rest.api.schema.CheckSchemaTest.get_user_API_Schema_Test(CheckSchemaTest.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: The file path should be relative to class path , try `statusCode(200).and().body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("\\test\\java\\com\\rest\\api\\schema\\getuserschema.json")); ` or`statusCode(200).and().body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath(".\\test\\java\\com\\rest\\api\\schema\\getuserschema.json")); ` or `statusCode(200).and().body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("test\\java\\com\\rest\\api\\schema\\getuserschema.json")); `

Comment: Any update ? On this

Comment: Yeah It has been resolve after your help, thanks

Comment: I have added it as answer could you please accepth and upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file path should be relative to class path , try
`statusCode(200).and().body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("\\test\\java\\com\\rest\\api\\schema\\getuserschema.json"));`

or

`statusCode(200).and().body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath(".\\test\\java\\com\\rest\\api\\schema\\getuserschema.json"));`

or

`statusCode(200).and().body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("test\\java\\com\\rest\\api\\schema\\getuserschema.json"));`